# Application of Leibniz's Formula

Tags: integration

I am given $$F(u) = \int_0^u (x+u)f(x)dx$$ and asked to calculate $F''(u)$.

My answer is as follows:

$$F'(u)=2uf(u)+\int_0^uf(x)dx$$
$$F''(u)=2uf'(u)+2f(u)+f(u)+\int_0^u 0dx=2uf'(u)+3f(u)$$.

Is this a correct application of Leibniz's formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the product formula where necessary:

$$F(u)= \int_0^u xf(x)~dx+u \int_0^uf(x)~dx \\
F'(x)=uf(u)+uf(u)+\int_0^uf(x)~dx=2uf(u)+\int_0^uf(x)~dx \\
F''(u)=2uf'(u)+2f(u)+f(u)=2uf'(u)+3f(u).$$

So you have the correct answer.